# Reactjs onClick toggle on off

Tags: reactjs

> i am trying to write code using useState  to toggle between on and off when clicking on button.

```
const [isON, setIsON] = React.useState(true)
<button onClick={() => setIsON(!isON)}>{ isON ? console.log('ON') : console.log('off') } />
```

i used this [website's](https://www.folkstalk.com/2022/07/react-button-toggle-on-off-example.html) code, but when i use this in react i get syntax error

Comment: you'll definitely need to tell use what error you are having at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably getting a syntax error both because you are calling functions where template should be AND because some HTML elements (such as `<button>`), can't be self-closing.
So `<button />` is not allowed, but if we REALLY want it to be empty,
we can do `<button></button>`.

But back to the main point,
React expects the returned value from your template tags to be either `string` \ `number` \ `null` or anything else that React considers a valid child.

The return value of a `console.log` is void, which isn't considered a valid React child.

In other words, you can't call `console.log` from within a tag in the template.
But if you really want it in your template, you can do this:

```
<button onClick={() => setIsON(!isON)}>Click me!</button>
{ isON ? console.log('ON') : console.log('off') }
```

Or better yet, use the ternary operator inside of the log function:

```
<button onClick={() => setIsON(!isON)}>Click me!</button>
{ console.log(isON ? 'ON' : 'off') }
```

Or even better yet, move it outside of the template as it has no business being there in the first place.
Since a React component re-renders whenever there is a change in state, the `console.log` can simply be put anywhere in the component instead.

```
function MyComp() {
   const [isON, setIsON] = React.useState(true)

   console.log(isON ? 'ON' : 'off')

   return (
      ...
      <button onClick={() => setIsON(!isON)}>Click me!</button>
      ...
   )
}
```